# Argo Events: passing variables from workflow through event payload to triggered workflow

Tags: yaml, argo-workflows, argo-events

I'm looking to setup argo-events to trigger a data-logging workflow when a "regular" workflow is submitted.
Following the [resource event source](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/eventsources/setup/resource/) docs, I can do this, but I cannot find how to encode and extract variables as is done using the [webhook parameterization](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/tutorials/02-parameterization/).

So I want to submit the following workflow:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: test-logger-workflow-
  labels:
    class: dummy-in
    submitaction: log-this
    wfuser: m-wf
    wfteam: a-wf
spec:
  entrypoint: whalesay
  templates:
  - name: whalesay
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay:latest
      command: [cowsay]
      args: ["hello world - manual submit - was log created?"]
```

and then access these labels in the trigger:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: resource-logger
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: test-dep-sensor
      eventSourceName: resource-wf-submit
      eventName: log-this
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: argo-workflow
        k8s:
          operation: create
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                generateName: resource-workflow-
                labels:
                  class: dummy-out
              spec:
                entrypoint: mylogger
                arguments:
                  parameters:
                    - name: user
                      value: default-name
                    - name: group
                      value: default-group
                    - name: description
                      value: triggered by argo submission
                templates:
                  - name: logger
                    inputs:
                      parameters:
                        - name: user
                        - name: group
                        - name: description
                    container:
                      image: logger:latest
                      imagePullPolicy: Always
                      command: [/app/logger.py]
                      args: ["-w", "argo-events", "-u", "{{inputs.parameters.user}}", "-t", "{{inputs.parameters.group}}", "-d", "{{inputs.parameters.description}}"]
          parameters:
            - src:
                dependencyName: test-dep-user
                ?? 
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
            - src:
                dependencyName: test-dep-group
                ??
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.1.value
            - src:
                dependencyName: test-dep-description
                ??
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.2.value
```

What do I need to put in in place of "??" to get the `wfuser` and `wfteam` values from the workflow?
Is there a generic way to access any of the workflow structure, e.g. populate the description with  the `image` value (`docker/whalesay:latest`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I had is that `spec.dependencies.name` (`test-dep-sensor`) and `spec.triggers.template.k8s.parameters.src.dependencyName` need to match, otherwise the latter isn't included/processed:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: resource-logger
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: test-dep-sensor
      eventSourceName: resource-wf-submit
      eventName: log-this
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: argo-workflow
        k8s:
          operation: create
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                generateName: resource-workflow-
                labels:
                  class: dummy-out
              spec:
                entrypoint: mylogger
                arguments:
                  parameters:
                    - name: description
                      value: triggered by argo submission
                    - name: user
                      value: default-name
                    - name: group
                      value: default-group
                templates:
                  - name: logger
                    inputs:
                      parameters:
                        - name: description
                        - name: user
                        - name: group
                    container:
                      image: logger:latest
                      imagePullPolicy: Always
                      command: [/app/logger.py]
                      args: ["-w", "argo-events", "-u", "{{inputs.parameters.user}}", "-t", "{{inputs.parameters.group}}", "-d", "{{inputs.parameters.description}}"]
          parameters:
            - src:
                dependencyName: test-dep-sensor
                dataKey: body
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
```